# Google Sheets: Auto Generating Checkboxes When New Row is Inserted

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

This might be a far fetched question, but is it possible to generate checkboxes when a new row is inserted?

Right now my new rows are my responses coming from a Google Form, I have checkboxes in place that when clicked, deletes the row and sends it to a "Completed" sheet. But the issue is that when that is done, it deletes the row and the checkboxes as well therefore every now and then, the user would have to re-insert a bunch of checkboxes.

And if I want to bring back the row from the "Completed" sheet back to the original sheet, it sends it directly to the bottom of the sheet because all the rows are populated with checkboxes.

Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the data validation to a checkbox but the contents of the cell must be TRUE, FALSE or blank.

```
var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("A1");
var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireCheckbox();
cell.setDataValidation(rule);
```